# Restart number from zero after hitting a maximum

Tags: python

I'm adding up two random numbers in order to get a new number between 0 and 359.

However, if the number surpasses 359, I want it to restart from 0. For instance, 300+180 should give 120, not 480.

Is there an easy way of doing so in Python?

Here's my code up until now:

```
rn = random.randint(0, 359)
rh = random.randint(0, 180)

color1=(rn+rh, 0.5, 1)
```

Comment: No reason to use numpy, just use `(rn + rh) % 360`.

Comment: standard method is to use `modulo 360` like in comments above - `np.mod(val, 360)` or `val % 360` but if you don't know modulo then you still could use loop for this `val = rn+rh` and `while val >= 360: val -= 360`